Why does LCMapStringEx fail to convert OLD HUNGARIAN CAPITAL LETTER A (U+10C80) to lowercase?
I tried invoking LCMapStringEx to convert OLD HUNGARIAN CAPITAL LETTER A (U+10C80) to lowercase (U+10CC0).
I expected the two UTF-16 code units 0xD803 0xDC80 of the capital form (U+10C80) to be converted to 0xD803 0xDCC0 in lowercase.
But what I get is a different result: in fact, the input sequence 0xD803 0xDC80 is left unchanged by LCMapStringEx.
What am I doing wrong?
Am I missing some flag in the dwMapFlags parameter?
This is a C++ repro code snippet (compiled with VS 2019 and executed under Windows 10):
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;

    // Old Hungarian Capital Letter A
    const wchar_t source[] = L"TEST \xD803\xDC80";  // U+10C80

    // Old Hungarian Small Letter A
    const wchar_t expected[] = L"test \xD803\xDCC0";  // U+10CC0 (lowercase of U+10C80)

    wchar_t dest[100];
    SecureZeroMemory(dest, sizeof(dest));

    //
    // Invoke LCMapStringEx to convert source string to lowercase
    //
    int result = LCMapStringEx(
        LOCALE_NAME_INVARIANT, // also tried with L"hu-HU" and nullptr
        LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING | LCMAP_LOWERCASE,
        source,
        -1,
        dest,
        _countof(dest),
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        0
    );

    if (result == 0)
    {
        // Failure
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        cout << "LCMapStringEx failed.\n";
        cout << "GetLastError returned " << errorCode << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    if (wcscmp(dest, expected) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Lowercase form is *not* what I expected.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "All right.\n";
    return 0;
}


Your code has 2 failure points, so which one is the actual problem? Is LCMapStringEx() returning 0 (if so, what is the error code?), or is wcscmp() reporting the strings are not equal?

This question is similar to: Rules for C++ string literals escape character. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RemyLebeau: It's wcscmp reporting strings are not equal. I explained that in the question; I said: what I expected is ... but what I get is...

@JosefZ: My question here has nothing to do with the question you linked.

I can't believe this question has two "close" votes!! I put time and energy to write a clear question, stating the problem, what I expected, what I got instead, and also wrote a reproducible compilable C++ code snippet.

Have you tried using the escape sequence \U00010C80 etc. instead of trying to encode surrogate pairs?

@Shawn: Thanks for the suggestion. Since I'm invoking a Windows API that expects UTF-16 strings, I wanted to create in memory the exact wchar_t sequence representing the UTF-16 encoding that the API should process.

@Shawn the problem has nothing to do with the character escaping.  The code and the data are perfectly fine. I can reproduce the same problem on my system. The problem is definitely with the runtime behavior of the API.

@RemyLebeau Yeah, me too. Looking at the bytes of source gets the same result with the explicit surrogate pairs or the unicode escape. I still prefer the unicode form as it's a lot more clear about what codepoint is being used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters doesn't mention anything about case mapping of codepoints beyond the BMP being supported, but it seems to focus mostly on GUI components so I don't want to say outright that "Windows just doesn't support what you're trying to do."

According to this article, Windows 10 comes with ICU. I'd use that for case conversion instead. (Though it apparently doesn't include the C++ parts of ICU, which are much nicer to use than the C API in C++ programs)

@RemyLebeau: Thanks for looking into it and for your confirmation of the issue. Considering this post on The Old New Thing blog, the LCMapStringEx API should work for this kind of conversion. I was thinking I may be misusing the API, like passing some wrong flag(s) or parameters, or missing to set some flags... I don't know, that's why I'm asking here. Thanks.

@Shawn: Thanks again for your comment. While certainly ICU could be an option, I'd like to make the LCMapStringEx API work for that conversion.

U+10C80 is from Unicode 8.0 (2015).  It's been around for a good while.  (I checked, just in case the Unicode code point was so new that Windows 10 doesn't known about it yet.)  And UnicodeData.txt (from 14.0) has 10C80;OLD HUNGARIAN CAPITAL LETTER A;Lu;0;R;;;;;N;;;;10CC0;, so the mapping to lowercase is there.

You might not be able to do it the way you want. (Anyone tested on Windows 11 to see if it properly lower cases the character there? If not I can tonight. Sure can't get it working on 10 no matter the locale or options)

@Shawn I've tried it out on Windows 11. The result was the same as OP's: the 0xD803 0xDC80 sequence was left unchanged.

I'd assume the script isn't supported in locale data, so I would expect the character to remain as is.

@Mr.C64 Old Hungarian was one of the scripts added in Windows 11. Rendering and font support was added. Not sure if support is in NLS.
